# Is there any way to hide default yAxes line and only show the values on yAxes in react-chartjs-2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have a little experience with chartjs but I am unable to find a way to hide the default line. I'm adding this image here which I need to fix.
I need to hide the line like this one
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXMpi.png.
I need to make it like this one
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phsos.png

If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), particularly the section regarding the use of images for text-based content, and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set display to false in the grid settings of the x axis and drawBorder to false in both axes like so:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          drawBorder: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You're actually telling me how to hide the gridlines but I don't want that. I've already hidden the horizontal gridlines. What I want is I want to hide that one vertical line along with y ticks as well. I've attached the picture for reference.

Comment: Did you run my example I attached for reference since you can see it does not show that line, also I tell you how to disable that line in my answer

Comment: Yes. I saw your example and it's exactly what I need but it's not working for me. I don't know why is that. Please refer to this which I'm using in my code https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/examples/vertical-bar-chart.